# Rotate openlayers fill pattern

Tags: html5-canvas, openlayers-3

I want to rotate line pattern fill inside openlayers feature. The rotation works well when testing outside openlayers, but when try to use it as feature fill color, rotation doesn't work.

```
p = ctx.createPattern(canvasPattern, 'repeat');

//the following code has no effect on p in openlayers, while it works independent on canvas
ctx.fillStyle = p;
ctx.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI / 4); // the most important!
ctx.fillRect(-cw, -ch, cw * 2, ch * 2);
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

featurePoly.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: p
  })
}));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nt6ae1Ld/23/

Comment: You might find the solution here: http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.style.pattern.html

Comment: Thx.U're a lifesaver!! :)